# VirtualKeyboard API not working in electron react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm working on an electron project that's running a react application in its browser.
I'm trying to hide the keyboard for specific input fields that are handled manually.

I've tried using the VirtualKeyboard API.

```
navigator.virtualKeyboard.hide()
```

This does not seem to work for me. My version from navigator.userAgent is.

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 Electron/18.3.4 Safari/537.36
```

According to this documentation it should work in Chrome.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/virtual-keyboard/